# Running MUnit gives error Invalid property name: `maskedRequestPath`

Tags: mule, munit

I have a flow that uses http:listener and apikit-soap:router. I recorded a MUnit test for the flow, executing the flow via SoapUI. When I run the generated MUnit, it fails with the following error:

```
"Invalid property name: `maskedRequestPath` on class `org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributesBuilder`. Validate that the correct setters is present.
```

The offending property is in the generated `set-event_attributes.dwl` file:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "connection": "close",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate",
    "content-type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
    "soapaction": "\"XXXXX\"",
    "authorization": "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "content-length": "218",
    "host": "localhost:88",
    "user-agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
  },
  "clientCertificate": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "scheme": "http",
  "queryParams": {},
  "requestUri": "/XXXXX",
  "queryString": "",
  "version": "HTTP/1.1",
  "maskedRequestPath": null,        <----- HERE
  "listenerPath": "/XXXXX",
  "relativePath": "/XXXXX",
  "localAddress": "/127.0.0.1:88",
  "uriParams": {},
  "rawRequestUri": "/XXXXX",
  "rawRequestPath": "/XXXXX",
  "remoteAddress": "/127.0.0.1:62993",
  "requestPath": "/XXXXX"
}
```

If I delete the `maskedRequestPath` line from this file, the MUnit runs OK.

I'm using Anypoint Studio 7.6.0 with Mule runtime 4.3.0.

Comment: Can you confirm the http connector dependency version from your pom.xml? and your munit version?

Comment: MUnit is 2.2.5 and and HTTP connector is 1.5.19. @RyanCarter